# Can't save password_reset_token to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm receiving an error in my tests, despite the code working. Is it normal for Capybara to throw an undefined method error for an attribute set in an instance method? My code is below:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :bio, :resume,
                  :website, :focus, :location, :aspirations, :password_reset_token, :profile_photo, :school,                                 :profile_photo_file_name, :profile_photo_content_type,                          :profile_photo_file_size, :profile_photo_updated_at

  attr_accessor :password_reset_token
  attr_reader :password

  validates :email, :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, allow_nil: true }
  validates :password_digest, presence: { message: "Password can't be blank" }

  after_initialize :ensure_session_token

  default_scope order('created_at ASC')

  has_attached_file :profile_photo, styles: { 
    medium: "250x250>", thumb: "50x50>" 
    }, convert_options: { :thumb => "-quality 75 -strip" 
  }

  has_attached_file :resume

  has_many(
    :roles,
    class_name: 'Role',
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    primary_key: :id,
    inverse_of: :user,
    dependent: :destroy
  )

  has_many(
    :taggings,
    as: :taggable,
    dependent: :destroy
  )

  has_many(
    :posts,
    class_name: 'Post',
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    primary_key: :id,
    inverse_of: :user,
    dependent: :destroy
  )

  has_many(
    :comments,
    class_name: 'Comment',
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    primary_key: :id,
    inverse_of: :user,
    dependent: :destroy
  )

  has_many(
    :honors,
    class_name: 'Honor',
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    primary_key: :id,
    inverse_of: :user,
    dependent: :destroy
  )

  has_many(
    :experiences,
    class_name: 'Experience',
    foreign_key: :user_id,
    primary_key: :id,
    inverse_of: :user,
    dependent: :destroy
  )

  has_many :courses, through: :roles, source: :course
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings, source: :tag

  def self.generate_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(16)
  end

  def self.find_by_credentials(email, password)
    user = User.find_by_email(email)

    return nil if user.nil?

    user.is_password?(password) ? user : nil
  end

  def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
  end

  def is_password?(password)
    BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest).is_password?(password)
  end

  def reset_session_token!
    self.session_token = self.class.generate_token
  end

  def full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end

  def set_password_reset_token
    self.password_reset_token = self.class.generate_token
  end

  def send_password_reset
    set_password_reset_token
    self.save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver!
  end

  private

  def ensure_session_token
    self.session_token ||= self.class.generate_token
  end

  def find_role(course_id)
    Role.select(:title)
        .where(user_id: self.id, course_id: course_id).first.title.titleize
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb**

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_current_user!

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

    user.send_password_reset if user

    flash[:notice] = "Email sent with password reset instructions."
    redirect_to signin_url
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "Password has been reset!"
      redirect_to signin_url
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                      :null => false
    t.string   "password_digest",            :null => false
    t.string   "first_name",                 :null => false
    t.string   "last_name",                  :null => false
    t.string   "session_token",              :null => false
    t.string   "bio"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "focus"
    t.string   "aspirations"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 :null => false
    t.string   "profile_photo_file_name"
    t.string   "profile_photo_content_type"
    t.integer  "profile_photo_file_size"
    t.datetime "profile_photo_updated_at"
    t.string   "resume_file_name"
    t.string   "resume_content_type"
    t.integer  "resume_file_size"
    t.datetime "resume_updated_at"
    t.string   "school"
    t.string   "password_reset_token"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["session_token"], :name => "index_users_on_session_token", :unique => true
```

**Capybara Error Message**

```
PasswordResets
  updates the user password when confirmation matches (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) PasswordResets updates the user password when confirmation matches
     Failure/Error: user.set_password_reset_token
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `password_reset_token=' for #<User:0x007fd237d31e20>
     # ./app/models/user.rb:107:in `set_password_reset_token'
     # ./spec/features/password_resets_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.19426 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/password_resets_spec.rb:23 # PasswordResets updates the user password when confirmation matches
```

Comment: So I removed attr_accessor and now I can save the column to the db, however, in my integration test, I'm still getting an error about the setter method being undefined. However, the password reset does work.

Comment: add password_reset to your `attr_accessible` list to allow you to set this value.

Comment: I forgot to add the edit that it is in the attr_accessible... do you think this is a bug from capybara since it actually works fine? Thanks again for your help Benjamin.

Comment: Whoops it was there but tabbed all the way to the right lol

Comment: Could you include the error/fail message from Capybara?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `attr_accessor` when you have a value that you don't wan to save into the database. In this case you don't need it since you want to save `:password_reset_token` into the db and rails will already provide setter and getter methods.

**EDIT**

Using `attr_accessor` changes the getter and setter methods and defines an instance variable. It does **not** change the attributes used by Active Record. This means when the model is saved, the values set with `attr_accessor` will not be saved to the database, even if the relevant column exists.

You can see what I mean when you print out the attributes:

```
u = User.new
u.password_reset_token = "abc"
u.attributes #=> { ... "password_reset_token"=>nil ... }
```

It doesn't make sense to use both `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible`  together on the same attribute. You should remove `attr_accessor :password_reset_token` from your model.

This may not solve the problem fully - but it should help you work out what the real problem is here.

I would recommend you write a unit test for `User#set_password_reset_token` to make sure it behaves the way you expect before writing your acceptance tests.

Comment: Hey Benjamin, thanks for the answer, but the issue isn't with the actual password. Its that the password_reset_token, which is supposed to be a 16-digit random string, doesn't save to the db. Even when I'm in the console and do something like self.password_reset_token = "abc", the reset_token doesn't save even though it says its valid and says that save! is true.

Comment: Also, the reason I used attr_accessor is because was getting a NoMethodError, password_reset_token= when I was doing self.password_reset_token = self.class.generate_token in the set_password_reset method.